# How can I get the PixelFormat of a Bitmap using .NET CF 2.0?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, bitmap

I'm trying to speed up performance of some image scaling & coloring routines in a mobile app based on .Net compact framework 2.0.  I've discovered the Bitmap.LockBits method, but how can I get a Bitmap's PixelFormat when the PixelFormat property is not supported in the compact framework?

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenNetCF Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) contains a BitmapData class that implements the PixelFormat property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of adding something that is not by default supported by .netCF. You can try the same approach.

http://blogs.msdn.com/chrislorton/archive/2006/04/07/570649.aspx